# JSON stringify adding quotes around entire json object and escaping characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js, stringify

I'm using `JSON.stringify()` at multiple points in my project, with unexpected varying behaviour.

I'm storing values in a events.json file writing back to update the state. When I remove an element from my `users` object array and write back, I'm left with the following in my file after writing back to it:

```
"{\"users\":[]}"
```

this is how it looked before the splice and writeback:

```
{"users":[{"sender":"xxxx","reciever":"xxxxx","amount":2}]}
```

at different parts of the project `JSON.stringify` does not surround the entire object with quotes nor escape quotation marks (including the previous write to my  `events.json` file as can be seen above). The resulting file produces incorrect JSON data and is no longer useful when I try to `JSON.parse()` it in the next read.

Any idea what I might be doing?

The line where I write the file back is:
`fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(parentObject));` and the parent object is well-formed before the write.

Comment: You dont need to pre-stringify `JSON.stringify`. That function is backwards reproducible with `JSON.parse`. It requires no work from you on setup other than being an array or object. But an array is an object

Comment: @GetSet what do you mean? `parentObject` is an object. Do you mean `writeFilSync` can take an Object?

I'm still interested to know why `stringify()` has this inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: I assume that somewhere you are double-JSON-stringifying.  Also, you are checking the actual file, and not looking at the JS debugger console, right?  Because the console will escape stuff for you too.

Comment: Suggest you check docs on param to `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @Brad you're right, I was inspecting what I thought would be the same object up the stack assuming there wasn't an extra `stringify` using the debugger. Thanks.

Comment: @TheThing No problem.  :-)

Comment: @GetSet I know, I was wondering about the inconsistent behaviour. Thanks for responding